# Source Control in VS Code has 10000 pending changes

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I use the source control to push to Github, but a while ago, i accidentally mixed the source control with my OneDrive, and i want to know how to get rid of this. I've tried removing the files, but i don't have permission, ive tried resetting the github source control extension and that doesn't work. Please let me know if you have a solution! [image: my 10000 changes]

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which folder you have opened and which files are in it, so I can't say for sure. But I can see you have pending changes in the .vscode folder. This folder should not be checked into version control.

Try adding a .gitignore file in the root folder and add the following line to it:

```
.vscode/*
```

.gitignore docs: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: where would i add the .gitignore?

Comment: You can put the .gitignore file in any subdirectory of the git project. Easiest way would be in the project root folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and managed to resolve it. Go to your vs-code terminal and write this code on it:

```
`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`
```

This command searches a `.git` folder that is higher up in the directory tree of your files and it will return the location of the first encountered git repository.
Now you have to Go to this directory and delete the `.git` folder. Wonder how to delete it as you can't see the folder? follow these steps:

1. click on view -> show -> click on hidden items
2. Now you can see the `.git` folder, delete it first then create a new folder and put the program files/folder (like C++ files or web development files) in it.
3. Now again freshly, open the vs code, open the new folder that you created, now in the left hand side click on source control (icon above run and debug), and click on initialize. And finally the problem get resolved, now you have zero pending changes.